# DBeaver SQL is there a option to revert your query?

Tags: sql, dbeaver

I'm pretty new to DBeaver and was wondering if it had an option to revert queries that were previously ran? For instance I ran

```
ALTER TABLE case_arrest_forms DROP CONSTRAINT cri_arrest_dispositionsid_fkey;
```

From the top menu it says it's on auto-commit. Is there a way for me to roll this back or would I have to add the constraint again? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Most likely you will have to simply re-add the constraint.  If the data hasn't changed, there shouldn't be any problems with doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, DBeaver doesn't have such kind of functionality. Can't revert query in auto-commit mode.
Also, it is not possible to return the row deleted from the table.

But to avoid such situations, you can [change the level](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Auto-and-Manual-Commit-Modes) of transactions.